# Limiting playback 2x Youtube api not working after the first video

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

In an online questionnaire, I intend to show embedded Youtube-video's to users. The problem is that every video should only be allowed to play twice. Thereafter, the video should be removed and replaced by a black box. After people answer a couple of questions, a new video & corresponding question will appear on the page.

I am running into trouble because my code only works for the first Youtube-video. From the second video-on, users can play my video's as often as they like. Can someone point to my error?

**HTML**

```
<div id="box" style="width:640px;height:360px;background-color:#000;">
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qp0EztigQew?enablejsapi=1&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="640"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var seen = false;
//console.log(seen);
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
      tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
                playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0 },
            }
        });
      }
function onPlayerReady(event) {
        // document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
      }
function doSomethingWithPlayerStatus(playerStatus) {

        if (playerStatus == -1) {
          // unstarted = gray
        } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
            console.log("end");
          // ended = yellow
          if (seen) {
            var video = document.getElementById("existing-iframe-example");
            video.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            seen = true;
          }
          //box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
          //box.style.minHeight="100px";
          //box.style.minWidth="383px";
          //create_DIV();


        } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
          // playing = green
        } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
          // paused = red
        } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
          // buffering = purple
        } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
          // video cued = orange
        }

      }
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        doSomethingWithPlayerStatus(event.data);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems going on here:
• If there are several video's on one page, then each of them requires an unique id in order to be referred to.
• The function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() is only called once, and that is when the first Youtube-movie is loaded. For the other movies, it won't refresh the varaibles.

First, create for every video an unique id. In this example, that is 'box_id1' and 'existing-iframe-example_id1':

```
<div id="box_id1" style="width:640px;height:360px;background-color:#000;">
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example_id1" height="360" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qp0EztigQew?enablejsapi=1&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="640"></iframe>
</div>
```

And adjust all references in your Javascript.

Then, call the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() again after each movie. BUT: it will throw back an error if your Javascript is loaded before the first Youtube-movie is loaded. So you can avoid calling onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() after the first movie.

```
var repeatedPlay;
if (repeatedPlay){
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
}
repeatedPlay = true;
```

As a note; please remove all code that is not necessary for your intentions; it makes everything more complicated. Your final result will be something like:

```html
var tag_id1 = document.createElement('script');
tag_id1.id = 'iframe-demo_id1';
tag_id1.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag_id1 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag_id1.parentNode.insertBefore(tag_id1, firstScriptTag_id1);
var player;
var seen = false;
var repeatedPlay;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 console.log("Youtube API called")
 player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example_id1', {
  events: {
   'onReady': onPlayerReady,
   'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
   playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0 },
  }
 });
}
if (repeatedPlay){
 onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
}
repeatedPlay = true;

function onPlayerReady(event) {
 // document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example_id1').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
}

function doSomethingWithPlayerStatus(playerStatus) {
 if (playerStatus == 0) {
  if (seen) {
  var video = document.getElementById("existing-iframe-example_id1");
  video.style.display = "none";
  console.log("hiding video");
 } else {
  console.log("changing parameter seen")
           seen = true;
 }
 //box_id1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 //box_id1.style.minHeight="100px";
 //box_id1.style.minWidth="383px";
 //create_DIV();
 }
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
 doSomethingWithPlayerStatus(event.data);
}
```